# Taylor polynomial about the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Find the 3rd degree Taylor polynomial about the origin of $$f(x,y)=\sin (x)\ln(1+y)$$

---

So I used this formula to calculate it $$p=f(0,0)+(f_x(0,0)x+f_y(0,0)y)+(\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(0,0)x^2+f_{xy}(0,0)xy+\frac{1}{2}f_{yy}(0,0)y^2)+(\frac{1}{6}f_{xxx}(0,0)x^3+\frac{1}{2}f_{xxy}(0,0)x^2y+\frac{1}{2}f_{xyy}(0,0)xy^2+\frac{1}{6}f_{yyy}(0,0)y^3)$$
I get $x(\ln(1)+y-\frac{\ln(1)x^2}{6}-\frac{y^2}{2})$

But as you can see, this is a very tedious task (especially if I have to do this on my midterm).

There exists a Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ and $\ln(1+y)$.
If I only keep the terms with degree $\le 3$, I have $$\sin(x)\ln(1+y)=(x-\frac{x^3}{3!})(y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}) \\=xy-\frac{xy^2}{2}$$

(I multiply the two and remove terms with degree > 3 from the answer)

The two polynomials are different. Is the second method even a valid way to determine Taylor polynomial?

Comment: Notice that $\ln(1) = 0$, and then your two series start to look rather identical ;)

Comment: If you write the Taylor series using multi-index notation, it is less ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are the same.  $\ln(1) = 0$.  And yes, your technique is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is a product of the form $f(x)g(y)$ this is valid.  If you had a term like $e^{-xy}$ instead, then one would have to use the full Taylor series formula that you mentioned above.

Comment: hum, is this true?