# Writing Taylor Expansion to degree three about a given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> Write the Taylor expansion to degree three about the given point for each function.
>   $$
> f(x,y)=3(x-1)^2 + 2y,~~~~~~ (x_0, y_0)=(0, 0)
> $$

I know how to do Taylor and Maclaurin series for single variable functions, but how do I go about doing this in multivariable.

Comment: Take a look here to this related OP for the general form ofbTaylor’s expansion at the origin https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542237/taylor-polynomial-about-the-origin

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function is in polynomial form thus we can simply expand it

$$f(x,y)=3-6x+2y+3x^2$$

that is the Taylor’s expansion at (x,y)=(0,0).